# Start python file in Swift

Tags: python, swift, python-3.x, nstask

I want to start a pythonscript by pushing a Button in a swift macOS application. I come up with:

```
let process = Process()
process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/python3"
process.currentDirectoryPath = "\(NSHomeDirectory())" + "/PycharmProjects/untitled5"
process.arguments = ["myscript.py"]
process.launch()
```

but I get "launch path not accessible" error by executing. If I change launchPath to:

```
process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/python"
```

everything works fine, but now I getting python compiling errors because myscript is written in python3.6.0, I have to use python3 because of using a library.
When I open Finder and go to "/usr/bin/python3" it says not found, but python3 is installed, I used it in Pycharm and I'm also able to start python3 in terminal.
In terminal "python3 ~/PycharmProjects/untitled5/myscript.py" works.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: What does `which python3` say? Are you sure, that it points to "/usr/bin/python3"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your terminal type

which python3

this will return the path that is accessed when you run python3 from the command line